# Display specific page in crystal report viewer c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, show-hide, crystal-reports-2010

i have a 3 buttons and a crystal report viewer. What i want to do is when i click a button, a specific page will be displayed in crystal report viewer. Ex: when i click button2 then page2 will be displayed. Can you guys help me with that please? I use c# by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below line :

```
  crystalreportviewer1.ShowNthPage(int);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).